# Hardy–Ramanujan number generalization

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory

\$1729\$, known as the [Hardy–Ramanujan number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1729_%28number%29), is the smallest positive integer that can be expressed as the sum of two cubes of positive integers in two ways (\$12^3+1^3=10^3+9^3=1729\$).  Given an integer \$n\$ (as input in whatever form is natural to your language of choice) find the smallest positive integer that can be expressed as the sum of two positive integers raised to the \$n\$th power in two unique ways.  No use of external sources.  Fewest characters wins.

Note that this is actually [an unsolved problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_taxicab_number) for \$n>4\$.  For those numbers, let your program run forever in search, or die trying!  Make it so that if given infinite time and resources, the program would solve the problem.

Comment: You may (?) want to specify "the sum of two *positive integers* raised to the `n`th power". Otherwise, `91` (not `1729`) is the solution for `n=3`, since `6^3+(−5)^3=4^3+3^3=91`.  I learned this from your Wikipedia link so maybe your H-M reference makes this unnecessary by convention.  Cheers!

Comment: actually, `1` is the first solution: `1 = cbrt(0.5)^3 + cbrt(0.5)^3 = ...`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and edit - I meant 2 positive integers!

Comment: @JanDvorak, ha, yes. Keeping it **R**eal!

Comment: You say "*find* the smallest positive integer that" ..., as though there *is* one -- but for any *n* > 4, the existence of such numbers is [an unsolved problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_taxicab_number). Maybe you should say "find the smallest positive integer (*if there is one*) that" ... It's possible that the "answers" are nonterminating loops that find nothing.

Comment: Yeah good call - I didn't realize that the problem was unsolved.  I'll add a note.

Answer (score 3):

## APL  <s>45</s>  41

```
{⍺←1⋄2≤+/,⍺=(v∘.≤v)×∘.+⍨⍵*⍨v←⍳⌊⍺*.5:⍺⋄⍵∇⍨⍺+1}
```

Shorter but slower version of 41 chars:

```
{⍺←1⋄2≤+/,⍺=(v∘.≤v)×∘.+⍨⍵*⍨v←⍳⍺:⍺⋄⍵∇⍨⍺+1}
```

You can try it [online](http://tryapl.com/), just paste the function and invoke it with a number:

```
      {⍺←1⋄2≤+/,⍺=(v∘.≤v)×∘.+⍨⍵*⍨v←⍳⌊⍺*.5:⍺⋄⍵∇⍨⍺+1} 2
50
      {⍺←1⋄2≤+/,⍺=(v∘.≤v)×∘.+⍨⍵*⍨v←⍳⌊⍺*.5:⍺⋄⍵∇⍨⍺+1} 3
1729
```

(The algorithm is quite dumb though, don't expect the online interpreter to compute n=4)

The answer for n=2 is 50 = 5² + 5² = 7² + 1² because its a number that "can be expressed as the sum of two squares of positive integers—doesn't say different—in two ways."

If you want to add the distinct clause, just change `(v∘.≤v)` into `(v∘.<v)`, same number of chars, and n=2 becomes 65:

```
      {⍺←1⋄2≤+/,⍺=(v∘.<v)×∘.+⍨⍵*⍨v←⍳⌊⍺*.5:⍺⋄⍵∇⍨⍺+1} 2
65
```

I'm beating GolfScript? Can't be!!

Comment: nice!  And I did mean distinct integers, but I didn't specify, so more power to ya!  Back to the drawing board for the GolfScript...

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 132

```
n=$*[r=0].to_i;while r+=1
r.times{|a|r.times{|b|next if
a**n+b**n!=r;r.times{|c|r.times{|d|puts(r)if
c**n+d**n==r&&a!=c&&a!=d}}}}end
```

Pass `n` as command line argument. First line to `stdout` is the solution.

Optimized for code-golf, not performance. (Runs correctly. But slow. Does more work than needed.)

---

Here is a longer, slightly faster C program. Same correct but horrible algorithm. (I really need to study more theory!)

Tested for `n`=2, `n`=3.

### C, 234

```
#include<stdio.h>#include<math.h>
r,a,b,c,d;main(n){scanf("%d",&n);while(++r){for(a=0;a<r;++a){for(b=a;b<r;++b){if(pow(a,n)+pow(b,n)!=r)continue;for(c=a+1;c<r;++c){for(d=0;d<r;++d){if(pow(c,n)+pow(d,n)==r&&a!=d)printf("%d\n",r);}}}}}}
```

The C version takes `n` on `stdin`. As above, first line to `stdout` is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

### GolfScript 53

```
1\.{;\).,{}@.@\{?}+%.`{\{+}+%~}+%$.`{\{=}+,,4=}+,.!}do)
```

Input is the initial number on the stack.  The number on top of the stack at the end is the answer.  I'll explain this in more detail when I get a chance.

E.g.

```
{1\.{;\).,@.@\{?}+%.`{\{+}+%~}+%$.`{\{=}+,,4=}+,.!}do)}:f
2 f -> 25 
3 f -> 1729
```

This is pretty slow right now. It also counts `0` (so that 25 is the answer for `n=2`, since `25=5^2+0^2=3^2+4^2`.  In order to not count 0, add the 2 characters `(;` after the first `,`

```
1\.{;\).,(;{}@.@\{?}+%.`{\{+}+%~}+%$.`{\{=}+,,4=}+,.!}do)
```

To find that `2 f=65`, since `65=8^2+1^2=5^2+6^2`

Answer (score 1):

### GolfScript (30 chars)

```
:N{).,{)N?}%:P{1$\-P?)},,3<}do
```

Note: this is quite slow, because it does a brute-force search rather than something elegant like a priority queue. The most elegant thing about it is reusing `N` as a lower bound from which to search: this is valid because `1^N + 2^N > N` for all `N`.

Takes `N` on the stack, leaves the corresponding taxicab number on the stack. To take `N` from stdin, prepend `~`.

The version above allows `x^N + x^N` (so for `N=2` it gives `50`). To require adding distinct numbers (giving `65` instead), change the `3` to `4`. To allow `0^N + x^N` (giving `25`), remove the `)` immediately before `N?`.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 58 chars

A very very slow solution using generating function:

```
0//.i_/;(D[Sum[x^(n^#),{n,1,i}]^2,{x,i}]/.x->0)/i!<4:>i+1&
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
Œċ*§ċ⁸=2
1ç1#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//xZLEiyrCp8SL4oG4PTIKMcOnMSP///8z)

This is *very* inefficient for \$n = 3\$ and doesn't complete within 60s. However, this can be fixed for an additional [4 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9Iy@ZY@6PGHUcnHek@tPxIN5Bpa8RleHi5ofL///@NAQ)

### How it works

```
Œċ*§ċ⁸=2 - Helper link. Takes an integer i on the left and a power n on the right
Œċ       - Yield all pairs, choosing with replacement
  *      - Raise each to the power n
   §     - Take the sum of each
    ċ⁸   - Count the occurrences of i in this list
      =2 - Is this equal to 2?

1ç1# - Main link. Takes a power n on the left
1    - Set the return value to 1
 ç1# - Return the first positive integer, i,
       where running the helper link with
      i on the left and n on the right is True
```